# How to include navigation bar with every page in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

This should be straight forward but I think I misunderstood the concept:

**Scenario:**

I've these custom components:

1. NavbarComponent
2. HomeComponent
3. ArticlesComponent
4. AskComponent
5. FooterComponent

Navbar should be displayed on all 4 components (HomeComponent, ArticlesComponent, AskComponent, FooterComponent).

**Screenshot of Home page (which is the default activated route)**

[image]

**Code:**

**app.component.html**

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

**Problem:**

Every activated route is rendered as child component of `app-navbar`. This is why the CSS property like height and width of navbar is inherited into all other components.

I suppose every component should be rendered as an individual component and not as child or sub-child.

[image]

**Live application**

[Here](http://social-coder.herokuapp.com/) you can inspect the element and please point out my mistake.

Comment: do you have a <router-outlet> inside NavbarComponent?

Comment: @VictorFernandes, Oh,yes. Yes I have it there as well

Comment: Yeah.. you should move the outlet to a higher level (that also has the navbar)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `<router-outlet></router-outlet` inside of your navbar component should provide you the behavior you are expecting.

I noticed (and as @VictorFernandes also mentioned) you have a `<router-outlet>` inside of your navbar component. In your case Angular sees the router-outlet in your navbar before it sees the one in the `app.component.html` file so it uses that one (in the navbar) as the DOM location to render your components which is why they are showing up as html nodes in your navbar.

Comment: Very well explained the problem and provided a working solution. Thanks both of you. :-)